# Unable to render square in directx9

Tags: directx, directx-9, square

```
// this is the function used to render a single frame
void render_frame(void)
{   
    init_graphics();

    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);

    d3ddev->BeginScene();

    // select which vertex format we are using
    d3ddev->SetFVF(CUSTOMFVF);

    // select the vertex buffer to display
    d3ddev->SetStreamSource(0, v_buffer, 0, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));

    // copy the vertex buffer to the back buffer
    d3ddev->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, 0, 2);
   // d3ddev->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, 0, 1);

    d3ddev->EndScene();

    d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}


// this is the function that puts the 3D models into video RAM
void init_graphics(void)
{
    // create the vertices using the CUSTOMVERTEX struct
    CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[] =
    {
        { 100.f, 0.f, 0.f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255), },
        { 300.f, 0.f, 0.f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255), },
        { 300.f, 80.f, 0.f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255), },
        { 100.f, 80.f, 0.f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255), },
    };

    // create a vertex buffer interface called v_buffer
    d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(6 * sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX),
        0,
        CUSTOMFVF,
        D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
        &v_buffer,
        NULL);

    VOID* pVoid;    // a void pointer

    // lock v_buffer and load the vertices into it
    v_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    v_buffer->Unlock();
}
```

Can't render a square for some reason. I've searched for an hour but can't find the answer.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1IlK.jpg
Does anybody know how to render it? I'm using directx9.
Tried using DrawIndexPrimitive but It has the same result.

Comment: Direct3D 9 is 15+ years old at this point, If you are new to DirectX, then Direct3D 11 is a better option and has many modern tutorials & utilities. For example, [DirectX Tool Kit for DX11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Answer (score 0):

There's likely a few things going on here:

1. You do not set a Vertex or Pixel Shader, so you are using the legacy fixed-function render pipeline. This pipeline requires you set the view/projection matrices with `SetTransform`. Since you haven't done that, the vertex positions you provide in 'screens space' don't mean what you think they mean. See [The Direct3D Transformation Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/the-direct3d-transformation-pipeline).
2. You are not setting the [backface culling mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling) via `SetRenderState` so it's defaulting to `D3DCULL_CCW` (i.e. cull counter-clockwise winding triangles). As such, your vertex positions are resulting in one of the triangles being rejected. You may want to to call `SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE);` getting started.
3. You are using `TRIANGLESTRIP` and only 4 points. You may find it easier to get correct initially by using `TRIANGELIST` and 6 points.